# Upgrading OpenSSL to v1.1.0 broke mongo (SSL peer certificate validation failed)

Tags: openssl, mongodb

I was trying to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster using the `srv` syntax, but it wasn't working. So I did the following:

1. Update my `mongo` client to the latest version (v4.0.11). Then every time I ran `mongo`, it said it couldn't find `libcrypto.so.1.1`.
2. Install OpenSSL v1.1.1 by following the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102803/how-to-upgrade-openssl-1-1-0-to-1-1-1-in-ubuntu-18-04).

Now it spits out the following:

```
$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-<redacted>.mongodb.net/test" --username <redacted>
MongoDB shell version v4.0.11
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-<redacted>.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-<redacted>.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-<redacted>.mongodb.net.:27017/test?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2019-08-03T17:42:56.502-0500 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-<redacted>.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-<redacted>.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-<redacted>.mongodb.net.:27017
2019-08-03T17:42:56.736-0500 E NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
2019-08-03T17:42:56.834-0500 E NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
2019-08-03T17:42:57.169-0500 E NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
2019-08-03T17:42:57.169-0500 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2019-08-03T17:42:57.173-0500 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2019-08-03T17:42:58.096-0500 E NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

and it keeps trying to connect and failing. It happens even if I run the *exact same* command (using the old MongoDB connection format) I could run before updating `mongo` and OpenSSL, so it has to be related to the updates. Searching on the Internet just returns a bunch of people with self-signed certificates, but I'm not doing that as I'm using MongoDB Atlas.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.